# How to sum array value in chart.js inside loop function?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have this function:

```
click: function(e) {
  map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());

  myJSON.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    if (arrayItem["Comune"] == e.target.feature.properties.NOME_COM.toUpperCase()) {
      $('.lead').html('');
      $('.lead').html('Comune di ' + arrayItem.Comune);
      $('#pulsante').html('');
      $('#pulsante').append('<div id="emptyred"><span style="opacity:0;">FMVPAFSB</span></div>')
      $('#pulsante').append('<div class="row" id="redditiButton"><div class="col-lg-6"><form><label class="radio-inline btn btn-danger"><input type="radio" id="generale" value="generale" name="radiored" autocomplete="off" checked> Generale</label><label class="radio-inline btn btn-danger"><input type="radio" id="dettaglio" value="dettaglio" name="radiored" autocomplete="off"> Dettaglio</label><label class="radio-inline btn btn-danger"><input type="radio" id="grafico3" value="grafico3" name="radiored" autocomplete="off"> Grafico3</label></form></div>')
      $('#chartContainer').append('<canvas id="Chartedu"><canvas>')

      var datiedu = {
        "labels": ['Lavori non terminati', 'Lavori in corso', 'Lavori terminati'],
        "datasets": [{
          label: 'Numero',
          data: [arrayItem['Value 1'], arrayItem['Value 2'], arrayItem['Value 3']],
          backgroundColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 51, 95)', 'rgb(255, 0, 55)'],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      };

      var datiedu2 = {
        "labels": ['Lavori non terminati', 'Lavori in corso'],
        "datasets": [{
          label: 'Numero',
          data: [I WANT SUM HERE],
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      };

      function grafo(dati, opzioni) {
        var grafobase = document.getElementById('Chartedu').getContext('2d');
        new Chart(grafobase, {
          type: 'doughnut',
          data: dati,
          options: opzioni
        });
      };
      grafo(datiedu);
    }
  });
}
```

How do I sum `arrayItem['Value 1']` and `arrayItem['Value 2']` so that I can put it in the data of var `datiedu2`? It has to be inside the condition, but it doesn't work. If I try I obtain only the total sum of myJSON... which isn't useful.

Comment: Ids have to be _unique_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for this like:

```
var datiedu2 = {
   "labels": ['Lavori non terminati', 'Lavori in corso'],
   "datasets": [{
      label: 'Numero',
      data: arrayItem.reduce((a, b) => a + ((b['Value 1'] || 0) + (b['Value 2'] || 0)), 0),
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderWidth: 1
   }]
};
```

Comment: it doesn't work! maybe because square brackets are missing? I tried to twitch it a bit but it still doesn't work

Comment: Where are square brackets missing?

Comment: in data maybe? like data: [bla bla]... or maybe there's another problem. Because it doesn't work (I tried to add them with no success)

Comment: Also, is `arrayItem` variable an array or object?

Comment: I think it's an array

Comment: Please share what you see in console when we use `console.log( arrayItem )`. If it is an object then data will be `(arrayItem['Value 1'] || 0) + (arrayItem['Value 2'] || 0)`.

Comment: omg it seems to work in this last way, thank you! and how do I divide the result of this for arrayItem['Value 3']?

Comment: you can store the sum in a variable and the divide it like `sum/arrayItem['Value 3']*1`